# Adding Line Break to Email Body Content of Mail.app Message Generated in AppleScript

Tags: macos, email, terminal, applescript, line-breaks

I'm currently using the below script to send out an email with a specified subject, attachment, and body message:

```
on run argv
    set theSubject to (item 1 of argv)
    set theAttachmentFile to (item 2 of argv)
    set theContent to (item 3 of argv)

    tell application "Mail"

        set theAddress to {"test@gmail.com"} -- the receiver 
        set theSignatureName to "Test" -- the signature name    

        set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true}

        tell msg
            repeat with i from 1 to count theAddress
                make new to recipient at end of every to recipient with properties {address:item i of theAddress}
            end repeat
        end tell
        tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachmentFile as alias}

        set message signature of msg to signature theSignatureName

        send msg
    end tell
end run
```

I have been executing the script in the Mac Terminal using:

`osascript /Users/dwm8/Desktop/email.scpt "Test" "dwm8:test.pdf" "Test Message Here"`

However, I would like to make a small change in regards to the body message of the email I send out. Instead of sending out the message

`Test Message Here`

I would like the body of the email to say

`Test
Message
Here`

where I am able to specify where I want a line break. Does anyone know how I can implement this into my existing script? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Add a carriage return:

```
osascript /Users/dwm8/Desktop/email.scpt "Test" "dwm8:test.pdf" "Test ^MMessage^M Here"
```

where ^M is what you get when you hit ctrl-v then ctrl-m.

Comment: I tried running that code and it puts `Test ^MMessage^M Here` as the body all on one line. Sorry, I'm new to AppleScript, so how would I go about altering the script to make this work? I would like this to be completely automated without having to use keyboard inputs.

Comment: your script is passed the entire contents.  You want the contents itself to have carriage returns.  You can't do that unless you know where you are putting them, so you need to do it when you call the function.  Try the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert carriage returns by using `\n` or `& return`:

```
"Test\nMessage\nHere"
```

or...

```
"Test" & return & "Message" & return & "Here"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried running `osascript /Users/dwm8/Desktop/email.scpt "Test" "dwm8:test.pdf" "Test\nMessage\nHere"` but, similarly to the other answer, yields a single-line body of `Test\nMessage\nHere`. Is this an incorrect implementation of your answer?

Comment: What is the purpose of "Test Message Here"? It might make more sense to include that in your `.scpt` perhaps. I haven't tried your script, but generally you can see the result of what is in my answer by doing `osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Test\nMessage\nHere"'` (at least that's how it normally should work).

Comment: I'm actually feeding the previously generated message from MATLAB to the script by using the `system()` function in MATLAB to run Terminal script. So a true sample message might look like "Jones/5/3/5 Smith 2/4/12/ Fisher 7/23/1", and what I would like is for each of those blocks of text to be on their own line.

Answer (score 0):

The content of your message is always the 3rd argument. This argument should not be the content, but you should have as many arguments as number of lines you want.

In example below, the call is done with 3 lines -> 3 arguments

```
osascript /Users/dwm8/Desktop/email.scpt "Test" "dwm8:test.pdf" "This is content of 1st line" "content of 2nd line" "test for the content of 3rd line"
```

Below the beginning of the script which can read as many arguments as you want :

```
set theSubject to (item 1 of argv)
set theAttachmentFile to (item 2 of argv)
set theContent to ""
repeat with I from 3 to (count of argv)
    set theContent to theContent & (item I of argv) & return
end repeat
```

Then add, at then end, the remaining part of your script from the tell application "mail" line. doing so, you can decide how to split line in the message content, at the call of the oascript function.